# ElasticSearch, specific field not returning

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I'm stuck with a little elasticsearch problem. I'm new to elasticsearch and don't know why this doesn't work.

```
curl -XPOST 'http://myhost.nl:9200/my_index/test/_search?pretty=true' -d '{ "fields": ["message"] }'
```

I don't get any field back. The field "message" does exist and realy looks like the example on the elasticsearch site. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/fields.html

Can anybody see what I'm missing?

Comment: Could you add mapping definition for your test type? You can look it up by running curl http://myhost.nl:9200/my_index/test/_mapping

Comment: Sorry I couldn't beautiefy it for you

{"test":{"properties":{"query":{"dynamic":"true","properties":{"query_string":{"dynamic":"true","properties":{"fields":{"type":"string"},"query":{"type":"string"}}},"querystring":{"dynamic":"true","properties":{"fields":{"type":"string"},"query":{"type":"string"}}}}},"tweet":{"dynamic":"true","properties":{"message":{"type":"string"},"post_date":{"type":"date","format":"dateOptionalTime"},"user":{"type":"string"}}}}}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query would have worked if this field was stored. But since it's not stored and only available as part of source, you need to specify full path to it. Try:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://myhost.nl:9200/my_index/test/_search?pretty=true' -d '{ "fields": ["tweet.message"] }'
```